# worklight dojo calendar navigation button overlapped

Tags: button, dojo, navigation, calendar, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm new in Worklight and I'm trying to make an hybrid application. 
I have a problem with Dojo calendar. 
At design time the calendar looks good, but in the preview, the navigation buttons are overlapped from the calendar. "Dojo Library Request" Asked me to add some library to the project and so I did.

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

(I can't add images because I don't have enough reputation)

This is my code until now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/dijit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="dojox/calendar/themes/claro/Calendar.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test1</title>
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/calendar/themes/claro/Calendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>

        
</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" style="display: none;" class="claro">

 <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0"
  data-dojo-props="selected:true">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
   data-dojo-props="label:'Teamwork Planning'"></div>
  <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" data-dojo-props="barType:'tabBar'">
   <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'AboutPage',transition:'slide'" id="Tab1">About</li><li
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'PlanningPage',transition:'fade'" id="Tab2">Planning</li><li
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'UpdateFieldPage',transition:'fade'" id="Tab3">Update field</li>
  </ul>

  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="AboutPage" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
   Questo e' un programma di test sviluppato da Antonio Cosentino:<br>
   <ul>
    <li type="disc">
     Cliccare sulla tab 'Planning' per creare nuovi appuntamenti del Gruppo di Lavoro
    </li><br>
    <li type="disc">
     Clicccare su update field per testare l'aggiornamento di un campo su Sqlserver
    </li>
   </ul>
   
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="PlanningPage" data-dojo-props="selected:false">

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.calendar.Calendar"
        data-dojo-props="dateInterval:'day'"
        style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 400px"></div>

  </div>
 


  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="UpdateFieldPage" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Questa tab serve a testare l'aggiornamento di un campo</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label>Codice Officina</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="fld_CodOff" onchange="fld_CodOff_OnChange()">
      </td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label>Ragione Sociale</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="fld_RagSoc">
      </td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
       <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="ButtonAggiorna" onclick="ButtonAggiorna_OnClick()">Aggiorna</button>
      </td>
     </tr>
     
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
 <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dojox/calendar has some limitations in the tooling. In order to resolve this, you need to manually copy the following from the dojoLib/toolkit/dojo tree into your project's dojo tree:

- dojox/calendar/themes/claro/*
- dijit/icons/*
- dijit/themes/claro/*   <-- Only a few files are actually needed here

Copy the first two directories in their entirety, then you should be able to use Chrome's web inspector to see which other files are showing 404 errors in the simulator and manually copy them over until things look correct.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Karl, I have copied the files/folders you told me into the project folder www. Probably I messed up with this folder before and now I don't know exactly how to fix it. As you said now it is asking me 3 new files but even if I add them with "Dojo Library Request" it ask me to add them again. I checked the "dojoLib/toolkit/dojo" tree and I can't find them. The three files are : layers/core-web-layer.js.map , dojo/dojo.js.map , layers/mobile-ui-layer.js.map.  Do you know where I can get those files ?

Comment: Those files are not present in Worklight Studio, but the error is harmless for the case you are facing. How your www folder looks now?

Comment: The .map files just enable debugging of compressed layers and are not important.  As far as the messed up /www directory, just create a new Dojo-enabled project/hybrid app, and copy the default tree over.

Comment: I made a complete new project I just added the calendar, I added the files "Dojo Library Request" asked me to, than it started to ask me the 3 files again. So I copied the entire dojo folder. It didn't change. I even created a new workspace without results ... so much time to add a calendar !!!  I think I'm going to change developing plan because I already lost too many time !!!  Thanks everybody for answering by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. apparently worklight 6.2 had some bug to fix. In fact I updated worklight (help-check for updates) and there were 3 updates to do. One of them was about Dojo. After that I created a new workspace and a brand new project and I noticed that with the new release they now create more files in the project when you add a calendar. BUT still something WAS missing. So I run the preview and I clicked on the phone and I have chosen to inspect the calendar : in this way I have been able to find all the missing files in my www folder. After I added them it eventually worked !!!!  After 25 years of service as programmer and all this technology, I can't believe you still need to do all this mess to add a controls in a form. Maybe .net spoiled me too much !!! :)